# WPScan - [ERROR] incompatible library version ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi_c.so

Tags: ruby, wordpress

I am looking to use WPScan to perform a security audit on several of my client's hosted WordPress sites on Xubuntu which I run here at the office.

I followed the install instructions for Ubuntu 14+ as well as RVM here:
https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan

However, I receive this error when attempting to run:

```
user@machine:~/wpscan$ ruby wpscan.rb
[ERROR] incompatible library version - /home/user/wpscan/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi_c.so
```

I can run it on Kali when I am home, but that would involve me working off the clock which I would like to avoid if possible. Also my work machine is fairly underpowered so running a VM would not be advised.  Seems if I can get the Ruby version correct it should work, however, I am unable to find which version is compatible via Google search and looking through the official documentation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ouch, they don't give a very useful error message. Sounds more like an issue for their tracker.

Comment: I thought of posting it there, but I wanted to run it by Stack first before submitting it to them directly.

Comment: Yeah, I agree as an open-source maintainer as well, the line is thin between issue and question.

Comment: Well I posted to them directly, prefaced with an apology, so we shall see what is returned.